# Type checking union types

Tags: node.js, typescript

**Consider the following code:**

```
interface CarData{
   wheels: number
}

interface PlaneData{
   wings: number
}

interface Vehicle{
   type: string,
   data: CarData | PlaneData
}

function printWheels(data: CarData){
   console.log("Number of wheels: " + data.wheels);
}

function printWings(data: PlaneData){
   console.log("Number of wings: " + data.wings);
}

let vehicle: Vehicle;

switch (vehicle.type)
{
    case "car":
        printWheels(vehicle.data);
        break;
    case "plane":
        printWings(vehicle.data);
        break;
}
```

I get the error `Argument of type 'CarData | PlaneData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CarData'.
  Property 'wheels' is missing in type 'PlaneData' but required in type 'CarData'.` which makes sense since it doesn't know what type data is. It can be solved by adding a shared member that tells the type. The following code type checks correctly:

```
interface CarData
{
    kind: "carData",
    wheels: number
}

interface PlaneData
{
    kind: "planeData",
    wings: number
}

interface Vehicle
{
    type: string,
    data: CarData | PlaneData
}

function printWheels(data: CarData)
{
    console.log("Number of wheels: " + data.wheels);
}

function printWings(data: PlaneData)
{
    console.log("Number of wings: " + data.wings);
}

let vehicle: Vehicle;

switch (vehicle.type)
{
    case "car":
        if (vehicle.data.kind == "carData") printWheels(vehicle.data);
        break;
    case "plane":
        if (vehicle.data.kind == "planeData") printWings(vehicle.data);
        break;
}
```

But this gives me extra values in data interfaces which I don't like. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why isn't the type property actually represented as something to discriminate on? Then your switch would also pick the right type. See e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 0):

You can do a switch directly on the discriminating field and TS will be able to work out that you are calling each function safely

```
switch (vehicle.data.kind) {
    case "carData":
        // vehicle.data is of type CarData
        printWheels(vehicle.data);
        break;
    case "planeData":
        // vehicle.data is of type PlaneData
        printWings(vehicle.data);
        break;
}
```

See [this TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygETmOyDeAsAFDJnIDWoAJgFzIBECG2uDANCecgO4AWECABsAzvRABXALYAjaCQC%20JEqEixEKAApC4ICKzxFS5KiDqMADjr0GOXcj1ABzMckmz5xJcRXho8JGQANQg%20YAQhFCNuMABPCwh6ETAoZ05jMmocOHp0LGzkAB9kbV19bMVlYhgJEAQwYAB7EGQLVPAAdQFhEQAKLNxclmyASgJ7MgRmkUbIgDohRqdehgA5aTkoZEaYXm7RegZkAGpkAbg5-kFREYBuSp9q2vqmlrbVDuc%208-pSm1HxhlkFMQDN5otlmsNtBtrtHCAXIcTmdspcvncHiRImBkAA3ULhSIAQnoITCEQg90eIkcYAQfGQvXx5Pm5zmpmoY2i5GYIhQTGGbFoE24yAA9GK8QSKXNzshgCJYcg4gk0IK4CLuO9Ovs%20szCRBZaMqaLyDIoBA4BQTTy4HzLNZykLNeQJVKWYa5QqlSqtI6DC6yNqwJ8EXrpazjYHkObLdaHkA) to see how this works without type errors

Comment: That is not really my problem, I want to get rid of the "kind"-member of the data objects